# Sharepoint designer set variable date to string in a different format?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

I am not sure of how to use expression in sharepoint designers.
I have a variable called date, but its type string.
I am attaching the workflow when an event is created.
I need to SET the variable date to the START DATE of the event.

But I need a particular format
YYYYMMDD

Something like this maybe:

```
=YEAR(Current Item:StartTime) + MONTH(Current Item:StartTime) + DAY(Current Item:Start Time)
```

[image]

Comment: or is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the link at the bottom, I created a designer workflow that will accomplish the above requirement.

*I should also note that ISODatetime should be a string, as well as dateYear, dateMonth, and dateDay

[image: Workflow Overview]
[image: Concatenation]

http://weblogs.asp.net/wesleybakker/archive/2010/12/28/get-datepart-in-sharepoint-designer-workflow.aspx

P.S.

As for why it is done this way...

SharePoint designer does not support free calculation as you would in say a c# programmed workflow or any type of code solution. In order to do calculations with SPD you have to use the given functions available and only those functions. Any type of calculation similar to the above would just be written out as plain text.

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Is this possible to do this in 2007?

Comment: It was very helpful, thank you so much for sharing!