# Collect Data from a User - Date and Time (without seconds)

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, tasks, date-time

I am creating a workflow in Sharepoint Designer 2010. In one of "collect task" I have a field "Meeting date":

- Information type: Date and Time
- Display format: Date and Time

My problem is that in task, user have to choose date and add time with seconds. And these seconds are a little annoying. Can I change time format in task form to have only date, hours and minutes?

Answer (score 0):

This is not SP2010 standard in tasklists. The tasklist has only Startdate and Duedate as only-date fields.
So this change to DateAndTime must have been done by someone for any reason.

You can take only the date in a variable as it is described within this question:
[Sharepoint designer set variable date to string in a different format?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/31951/sharepoint-designer-set-variable-date-to-string-in-a-different-format)