# Convert Todays Date to a format that can be used in a SharePoint Workflow call http service action

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, designer-workflow, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to call REST API Inside a **SHAREPOINT Designer Workflow** based on a date query.

my filter string is

> $filter=Created le '2019-04-28'

however, Instead of the date value, I need a dynamic date of today minus 180 days and in the right format.

I was able to get the 180 days before by adding -180 days to the date variable.

But the date I get is in

> "4/28/2019"

format.

Any suggestions on changing the / to - and changing the position of M,D,Y ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was eventually able to create the date format by extracting separately, all components of the date. by following the below steps

[image: This worked because ISO format luckily had year month and days at fixed character indexes]

[image: create the filter using the individual variables]

Answer (score 1):

You can use below function to convert your date variable in `yyyy-mm-dd` format:

```
function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) 
        month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) 
        day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
}
```

**Usage**:

```
alert(formatDate(new Date()));
```

**Date before 180 days from today**:

```
var dateObj = new Date();
dateObj.setDate(d.getDate()-18);

//Use above function to convert it in yyyy-mm-dd format
alert(formatDate(dateObj));
```

**Reference**: [Format JavaScript date as yyyy-mm-dd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-as-yyyy-mm-dd).

**Update - Using SharePoint Designer workflow**:

Note that SharePoint REST API uses date is **ISO Date Format** for filtering.

To get the date parts in SharePoint designer workflow you need to use **Extract Substring from End of String** action in designer workflows.

You can set the date by subtracting 180 days from today's date and then you can extract date, month, year parts from date and build/set a workflow variable in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

Check below references which will help you achieve your requirements:

1. [Sharepoint designer set variable date to string in a different format?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/31951/sharepoint-designer-set-variable-date-to-string-in-a-different-format)
2. [Need to get "DATE" to format YYYYMMDD-ID, is it possible using just Workflow?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9d990427-5592-42cc-9825-b5dc46e39079/need-to-get-quotdatequot-to-format-yyyymmddid-is-it-possible-using-just-workflow?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)
3. [Workflow actions in SharePoint Designer 2013](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/workflow-actions-quick-reference-sharepoint-workflow-platform#workflow-actions-in-sharepoint-designer-2013).

Comment: Thanks Ganesh. After seeing your solution. I just forgot that my scenario is inside a SharePoint Desginer Workflow. I now edited my original question.

Comment: Then you need to add more details to your question. Which version of SharePoint you are using? Which version of designer workflow you are using? :)

Comment: 2013 Designer. on Online O365

Comment: See updated answer. Please upvote and accept it as an answer if it helps you. As you are using O365, you can also look for using Microsoft flow as a replacement for designer workflow.

Comment: Please Accept it as an answer if it helped you to get the solution for your question.